# Kivy: BoxLayout vs. GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

`BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')` vs. `GridLayout(cols=1)`:

They both do the same thing, no? Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: BoxLayout __probably__ has less work to do under the hood ... but its marginal I would imagine.  so go with what feels naturak for that.  I personally think a vertical boxlayout better describes what it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The differences involves size and position.

In general, **`GridLayout` (`cols: 1`) is always going to keep the elements in one column**, whereas **there is more flexibility to organize individual widgets when you use `BoxLayout` (`orientation: 'vertical'`)**.

Here is a very simple example of something you can do with `BoxLayout` because it honours `pos_hint`, `size` and `size_hint` (and others such as `center_x`, `x`, `y`, `right`, - notice that they also depend on the `vertical` or `horizontal` orientation of the `BoxLayout`) which affects individual widgets:

```
<Test@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'a'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100,50
        pos_hint: { 'center_x' : .5 }
    Button:
        text: 'b'
```

This is the output in a 200x200 screen:

[image: BoxLayout with vertical orientation]

If you attempt to do the same but using `GridLayout` instead, then you get this:

[image: GridLayout with cols: 1]

Finally, `GridLayout` has some properties to control the size of the column:

- `col_default_width`: for the default width of all the columns
- `col_width`: a list of widths for each column (not useful in this
  case since we have just one)
- `col_force_default`: which will ignore any existing `size_hint` or `size` for individual widgets and force the column width
- `minimum_width`: so the column not shrink too much