# Making a layout with variable number of columns per row in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

In kivy, what is the preferred way to make a screen that has a variable number of columns per row? Is there a way to accomplish this without explicitly specifying the positions and sizes of the widgets in a layout (i.e. is there a way to do this as if you were stacking a bunch of GridLayouts with different numbers of rows and cols within a Screen)? What is the way to do this using only python code?

For instance, let's say you have a Screen which contain some type of Layout, called "layout_scr1". How would you go about arranging things so that, for example, the first row of layout_scr1 contains 1 column, the second row contains 2 columns, and the third row contains 4 columns?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few options, but I think the simplest way would be using `BoxLayout` instead of `GridLayout` or even `StackLayout`. `StackLayout` could go to a second row the width is not enough whereas `BoxLayout` and `GridLayout` stays on the same line. You can find and explanation of the difference between `BoxLayout` and `GridLayout` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222194/kivy-boxlayout-vs-gridlayout/18237038#18237038).

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Boxes>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                BoxLayout: 
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: 50
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "1"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "2"
                        Button:
                            text: "3"
                        Button:
                            text: "4"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "5"
                        Button:
                            text: "6"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        Button:
                            text: "7"
                        Button:
                            text: "8"
                        Button:
                            text: "9"
                        Button:
                            text: "10"
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'Another Screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")

class Boxes(FloatLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Boxes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

If you still want to use `GridLayouts` you can substitute:

```
BoxLayout: 
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

for this:

```
GridLayout: 
    cols: 1
```

and this:

```
BoxLayout: 
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

for this:

```
GridLayout: 
    cols: 1
```

And just in case you were looking for a more dynamic approach:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string("""
<Boxes>:
    boxes: _boxes 
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ScreenManager:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            id: _screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: 'screen1'
                BoxLayout: 
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: 50
                    id: _boxes
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                Label: 
                    text: 'Another Screen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 1'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
            Button:
                text: 'Go to Screen 2'
                on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'screen2'""")

class Boxes(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Boxes, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bx1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        bx2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        bx3 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        bx4 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        for i in range(1,2):
            bx1.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        for i in range(2,5):
            bx2.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        for i in range(5,7):
            bx3.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        for i in range(7,11):
            bx4.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))

        self.boxes.add_widget(bx1)
        self.boxes.add_widget(bx2)
        self.boxes.add_widget(bx3)
        self.boxes.add_widget(bx4)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Boxes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and give it a try.